# Filter or order based on custom field

Tags: custom-field, sort, loop, filters

I have added a custom field to some posts called 'frontpagerank'
The plan is to order the posts by this value but first I just want to filter out any that don't use a front page rank.
I have achieved this by putting the relevant posts into another array.
But what to do next?

Also tried a query:
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'meta_key' => '0', 'meta_value' => '44' ));

```
while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); $count++;
```

This just does nothing. This code is hard to debug!

Comment: I guess this should read while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); $count++;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have added a custom field to some posts called 'frontpagerank'

Then shouldn't the WP_Query args reference that key then, eg.

```
'meta_key' => 'frontpagerank'
```

If i follow, you want to check for posts that have this key, and you're expecting a numeric value, so i'll naturally assume you don't want posts with this key(but an empty value).

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'meta_key' => 'frontpagerank', 'meta_value' => '', 'meta_compare' => '!=', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' ));
```

Or if you specifically want to check for posts with that meta_key where the value is above say 0, you could do..

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'meta_key' => 'frontpagerank', 'meta_value' => '0', 'meta_compare' => '>', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' ));
```

You can read info on the meta parameters here.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters

Info on order by to, since i added that into the above to.. ;)
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

..any parameters you see listed for query_posts can be used inside WP_Query

Then all you need do is loop over that data like you had earlier..

```
// Note i made the correction you commented on, yes that's need to match
while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

   // do whatever

endwhile;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Though really i should have used `meta_query` instead here, i've no experience using it yet, so i've shown how to use the pre 3.1 method.

Comment: Ok thanks. Seems to be working ok,  but only when I unstuck the sticky posts. Is there a way to stop sticky posts? I commented out this line  // $sticky=get_option('sticky_posts');

Comment: Commented it out of where?

Comment: I am using a theme called IsoTherm : [link]http://bizzthemes.com/themes/isotherm/ Without posting the whole source from the page, I can tell you that is the only reference to sticky in the source code.

Comment: I don't need to see all the code, i'm trying to work out what your question is regarding stickies, i don't follow what it is your're asking. Do you want to exclude sticky posts from the query?

Comment: Ok, I will rephrase. Can I disable the sticky posts feature?

Comment: As in, totally disable the feature, or just unstick any currently stuck post?

Comment: Totally disable

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but this seems like it should work:

```
$recent = new WP_Query("meta_key=your-custom-field&orderby=meta_value");
```